# Can anyone explain why the Swiss balance of payments is not balanced (real data)?

Tags: macroeconomics, international-economics, open-economy-macro, balance-of-payments

While doing a little research I went to the Swiss National Bank's website and downloaded their data on the Swiss balance of payments.
The data is here:
https://data.snb.ch/en/topics/aube#!/cube/bopovera

However the data on the SNB website does not sum to 0. [Using the sum current account +the capital account + financial account = 0 (BoP)]
There's even a column in the data for the statistical difference but even including this there was no way that I could get the columns to balance.

I also looked on Trading Economics, it would also seem that there is no "balance" in the BoP. Switzerland would appear to be running a surplus in both accounts (see below). Ok Q1 2021 looks close. But I'd expect them to be mirror images of each other for every quarter.

Can anyone explain?
[image: Swiss current account]
[image: Swiss financial account]

Comment: Hi. I thought someone had answered this but their answer seems to have disapeared. 

I am still confused. 
All the sources I am looking at stat that by definition they balance.

Comment: Moreover the UK is running twin deficits:
_
A current account deficit places the UK as a net borrower with the rest of the world, indicating that overall expenditure in the UK exceeds national income. The UK must attract net financial inflows to finance its current (and capital) account deficit, which can be achieved through either disposing of overseas assets to overseas investors or accruing liabilities with the rest of the world._ 
'
https://www.ons.gov.uk/economy/nationalaccounts/balanceofpayments/bulletins/balanceofpayments/januarytomarch2020#financial-account